# Help me to Find $\frac{a_{7}}{a_{13}}$ in $(2x^2+3x+4)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_{r}\times{x^r}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to find cofficients using binomial theorem but it involves lot of calculations.Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Question says: Given$(2x^2+3x+4)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_{r}\times{x^r}$
Find $\frac{a_{7}}{a_{13}}$

Comment: Your last three posts are all problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: What is the source of this question, please, Paras?

Comment: This is in my assignment given by maths teacher.He usually gives us previous olympiad questions.

Comment: I got answer,it is 534827520/66853440=8

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any formal Laurent series $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k z^k$ in any indeterminate $z$, let $[z^n](\cdots)$ be a short hand for the coefficient $c_n$.
i.e
$$ [z^n] \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k z^k \stackrel{def}{=} c_n$$

In general, if we perform a change of variable $w = \alpha z$, the coefficients between $w^n$ and $z^n$ are related by a power of $\alpha$.

$$\alpha^n[w^n] (\cdots) =  [z^n] (\cdots)$$

Let $x = \sqrt{2}y$, we have
$$\begin{align}
a_7 &= [x^7] (2x^2 + 3x + 4)^{10}
= [x^{-3}]\left(2x + 3 + \frac{4}{x}\right)^{10}\\
&= \sqrt{2}^3[y^{-3}]\left(\sqrt{8}\left(y + \frac1y\right) + 3\right)^{10}\\
a_{13} &= [x^{13}](2x^2 + 3x + 4)^{10}
= [x^3]\left(2x + 3 + \frac{4}{x}\right)^{10}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^3}[y^3]\left(\sqrt{8}\left(y + \frac1y\right) + 3\right)^{10}
\end{align}$$
Notice the common expression $(\cdots)$ after $[y^{\pm 3}]$ are invariant under $y \mapsto \frac1y$. This leads to

$$[y^{-3}](\cdots) = [y^3](\cdots)\quad\implies\quad
\frac{a_7}{a_{13}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}^3}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^3}} = 8$$.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it
$(2x^2+3x+4)^{10}=a_{0}x^0+a_{1}x^1+a_{2}x^2+...+a_{20}x^{20}$
Expanding by binomial theorem, taking $(2x^2+4)$ as single term , will expand it later
${10\choose 0}(2x^2+4)^{10}(3x)^0+{10\choose 1}(2x^2+4)^9(3x)^1+{10\choose 2} (2x^2+4)^8(3x)^2+{10\choose 3} (2x^2+4)^7(3x)^3+...{10\choose 10}(2x^2+4)^0(3x)^{10}=a_{0}x^0+a_{1}x^1+a_{2}x^2+...+a_{20}x^{20}$
Comparing cofficients of $x^7$ and $x^{13}$ both sides gives you $\frac{a_{7}} {a_{13}}$
Hint: in LHS terms involving cofficients
${10\choose 1} , {10\choose 3} ,{10\choose 5} ,{10\choose 7}$ only will give you cofficents of $x^7$ and $x^{13}$, other terms won't.

After solving,
$\frac{a_{7}} {a_{13}}=\frac {534827520}{66853440}=8$

Alternate method:(hard to think):

Replacing x by $\frac {2}{x}$ ,we get

$({{\frac {8}{x^2}}+{\frac {6}{x}}+4)}^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{{20}}a_{r}\times{\frac{2^r}{x^r}}$

$\frac {2^{10}(2x^2+3x+4)^{10}}{x^{20}}=\sum_{r=0}^{{20}}a_{r}\times{\frac{2^r}{x^r}}$

$2^{10}(2x^2+3x+4)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{{20}}a_{r}\times{2^r}{x^{20-r}}$

$2^{10}(\sum_{r=0}^{{20}}a_{r}\times{x^r})=\sum_{r=0}^{{20}}a_{r}\times{2^r}{x^{20-r}}$
Put r=7

${2^{10}}{a_{7}}={2^{13}}{a_{13}}$

So,$\frac{a_{7}} {a_{13}}=2^3=8$

Probably this subsitution works because after subsitution we again got $(2x^2+3x+4)^{10}$ with some extra constant. Moreover with this subsitution we can only find ratio of only specific cofficients not all the cofficients

Comment: Is there an easier way? Computing $a_7$ and $a_{13}$ to give those values seems very tedious

Comment: Well there is another way i asked my teacher, he said replacing x by 2/x will give you ratio directly by simple rearrangements

Comment: There are too many braces in your edits, incidentally. e.g. `{a_{b}}` generates the same thing as `a_b`. Simpler expressions such as the latter in my example will make formatting LaTeX easier.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^{10}$ and $g(x)=2x^2+3x+4$. Then what you have is $f(g(x))$. You can find the $7$th derivative of this using [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

$$\left.\frac{d^7}{dx^7}f(g(x))\right|_{x=0}=\sum_{m_1+2m_2+\cdots+7m_7=7}\frac{7!}{m_1!1!^{m_1}\cdots m_7!7!^{m_7}}f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_7)}(g(0))\prod_{j=1}^7\left(g^{(j)}(0)\right)^{m_j}$$

Now $g$'s 3rd derivative is $0$, so we need only consider terms in the sum where $m_3=m_4=\cdots=m_7=0$. In other words:

$$
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{d^7}{dx^7}f(g(x))\right|_{x=0}
&=\sum_{m_1+2m_2=7}\frac{7!}{m_1!1!^{m_1}m_2!2!^{m_2}}f^{(m_1+m_2)}(g(0))\cdot g'(0)^{m_1}g''(0)^{m_2}\\
&=\sum_{m_1+2m_2=7}\frac{7!}{m_1!m_2!}\frac{10!}{(10-m_1-m_2)!}4^{10-m_1-m_2}\cdot 3^{m_1}2^{m_2}\\
&=\sum_{m_1+2m_2=7}\frac{7!}{m_1!m_2!}\frac{10!}{(10-m_1-m_2)!}2^{20-2m_1-m_2}\cdot 3^{m_1}
\end{align}
$$

There aren't all that many terms in the summation. The options for $(m_1,m_2)$ are $(7,0)$, $(5,1)$, $(3,2)$, and $(1,3)$. Let $j$ run through $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and have $m_1=7-2j$, $m_2=j$.

$$
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{d^7}{dx^7}f(g(x))\right|_{x=0}
&=7!\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{10}{(7-2j)\quad j\quad(j+3)}2^{3j+6}\cdot 3^{7-2j}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now the same thing will work for the $13$th derivative. But note that $f$'s derivatives vanish at the $11$th, so the terms to consider for $(m_1,m_2)$ are $(7,3)$, $(5,4)$, $(3,5)$, $(1,6)$. That, is, let $j$ run through $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with $m_1=7-2j$, $m_2=j+3$.

$$
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{d^{13}}{dx^{13}}f(g(x))\right|_{x=0}
&=13!\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{10}{(7-2j)\quad (j+3)\quad j}2^{3j+3}\cdot 3^{7-2j}
\end{align}
$$

So we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_7}{a_{13}}&=\frac{\frac{1}{7!}\left.\frac{d^{7}}{dx^{7}}f(g(x))\right|_{x=0}}{\frac{1}{13!}\left.\frac{d^{13}}{dx^{13}}f(g(x))\right|_{x=0}}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{10}{(7-2j)\quad j\quad(j+3)}2^{3j+6}\cdot 3^{7-2j}}{\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{10}{(7-2j)\quad (j+3)\quad j}2^{3j+3}\cdot 3^{7-2j}}=2^3=8\\
\end{align}
$$